# How to build devise controller that can accept request from outside of the rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is the devise route:

```
devise_scope :user do
  post 'log-in/testing', to: 'sessions#create_session'
end
```

and here is the controller:

```
class SessionsController < DeviseController

  def create_session
    database = permitted_params[:database]
    session_id = permitted_params[:sessionId]
    user_name = permitted_params[:userName]

    # the rest of the logic
  end
end
```

and I wand to send request to the endpoint like:

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/log-in/testing' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "database":"database",
    "sessionId":"OUZS_onnmm",
    "userName":"pra@gmail.com"
}'
```

but I get 422 error, I added byebug at the beginning of the controller, but it's not triggered.

It looks like the post controller in devise can be accessed by html pages within the rails app, but can we build a devise controller that can be accessed by outside applications, eg from a Angular or React app?

Comment: https://medium.com/@alessandrahagarty/using-devise-for-authentication-in-a-react-rails-app-f6a0eb87fbd5

Answer (score 0):

I find that the 422 was due to verify_authenticity_token

skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create_session